# windows Vim YouCompleteMe auto-completion

Tags: php, windows, vim, autocomplete

Although there's no official support for windows environment it seems that numerous people have been successful in getting this work.
I desparately trying too but without success.
All what I need now is working autocompletion for php files (omni-completion, keyword completion).

I'm running x64bit version of compiled Vim 74 (+python27, +python33) [here](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows/downloads)
From same guy I downloaded YouCompleteMe compiled for windows [here](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/src)

I installed plugin as always with [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) plugin.
I've installed Python27 & Python33 (x64) and I've both placed in my PATH. (Also python27.dll in windows/System32/directory)

In this state. if I ran Vim, I was getting **error:**

> "*The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ...). Stder (last 30
>   lines)..."*

on vim startup. In same time **Error log said:**

> RuntimeError: Error importing ycm_core. Are you sure you have placed a version 3.2+ libclang.[so|dll|dylib] in folder
>   "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python"?

So I provided [libclang.dll](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/llvm-for-windows/downloads) in specific folder (x64bit version) although I was editing a php file (not c family file) so this isn't relevant. Is it?

OK so now I'm in situation where I still get error on startup:

> "*The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ...). Stder (last 30
>   lines)..."*

but Error log has been changed, it says:

> DEBUG - No global extra conf, not calling method YcmCorePreload
>   Traceback (most recent call last):     File "C:\Program
>   Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server../..\ycm\server\handlers.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       import ycm_core   **ImportError: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of Python.**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "C:\Program
>   Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server/ycmd.py",
>   line 126, in 
>       Main()   File "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server/ycmd.py",
>   line 115, in Main
>       from ycm.server import handlers   File "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server../..\ycm\server\handlers.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       str( e ) ) ) RuntimeError: Error importing ycm_core. Are you sure you have placed a version 3.2+ libclang.[so|dll|dylib] in folder
>   "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python"? See the
>   Installation Guide in the docs. Full error: Module use of python27.dll
>   conflicts with this version of Python.

What does it meen? I'm pretty sure that I've required version (Python 277 x64bit).
What can I do? Could someone help me who got this working on windows environment?

### **UPDATE:**

@sooop's answer pushed me a little bit forward, it helped.
Problem was that in PATH I had in front of "c:\Python27" placed "c:\Python33". So it found first provided python version and quit searching for Py27. So I placed "c:\Python27" before "c:\Python33" and this message disappeared.

Unfortunately another error occured: Now error log says:

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server../..\ycm\server\handlers.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       **import ycm_core ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server/ycmd.py",
>   line 126, in 
>       Main()   File "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server/ycmd.py",
>   line 115, in Main
>       from ycm.server import handlers   File "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python\ycm\server../..\ycm\server\handlers.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       str( e ) ) ) RuntimeError: Error importing ycm_core. Are you sure you have placed a version 3.2+ libclang.[so|dll|dylib] in folder
>   "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\you-complete-me\python"? See the
>   Installation Guide in the docs. Full error: DLL load failed: %1 is not
>   a valid Win32 application.

Unfortunately I do not know what to do at all as well.

### **SOLUTION**

@sooop's answer solves both of the two last errors. [YouCompleteMe plugin](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/src) supports only Python27 (and Py26). And path to the "\Python27\python.exe" in %PATH% environment variable must be at the first position, in front of other python versions!

Comment: For what it's worth, YCM does nothing special for PHP completion: it only uses Vim's own omnicompletion script so, if you only need PHP completion, you could drop that monster and its crazy dependencies for a more lightweight and easy to install "auto-" or "tab-" completion plugin like [AutoComplPop](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-autocomplpop/) or [VCM](https://github.com/ajh17/VimCompletesMe).

Comment: Yeah, well I didn't express properly. Now I use AutoComplPop plugin but it's pretty limiting. It only collect keywords from opened buffers. Aside from AutoComplPop I also use [tern](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim) for semantic JavaScript autocompletion. But I hate when I must always press key combination for triggering popup menu. I want it to be shown automatically. Another possible benefit from using YCM would be integrating eclim plugin for better php autocompletion.

Comment: I've made [this fork of ACP](https://github.com/romainl/acp-forked) to support JS and PHP.

Comment: Oh, thank you @romainl ! I tried that and it's definitely a lot better. Especially for JavaScript with combination of tern. For php it's also better than before. Could it trigger omni-completion if "->" is typed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove path th python3 from your %PATH%.

Comment: Actually, You're right. I totaly forgot that I've installed one more python version and I overlooked it in my PATH.
So I placed it after "c:\Python27\" too. Now it's working... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative and IMHO cleaner solution is to refer ycm to you python executable explicitly. To do so, put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = 'c:\Python27_64\python.exe'
```

where `c:\Python27_64\python.exe` should be replaced by the full path to your python executable. Note that its architecture (i.e. 32 or 64 bit) should match your vim architecture.